# Run a command and inquire on that command while still running

Tags: bash, shell-script

I can't understand why this line won't work

```
firefox & xdotool search --name firefox > file
```

`xdotool search --name firefox` is supposed to find a window whose title contains word "firefox" and returns a number. I need it redirected to a file to use it later. Point is,

```
chromium-browser & xdotool search --name firefox > file
```

and

```
firefox & xdotool search --name chromium > file
```

work perfectly, problem must be either time needed to map a window (but putting a `sleep 10` inbetween didn't solve) or the task can't be done in the same shell. I need the second command to run right after (or some seconds after) the first one starts, not when it's done.

The second command will only produce output if I launch it after the other from the same terminal shell or in another shell, but not together like in the mentioned example. I tried with `disown` and `nohup` and I tried with a second `&` at the end, didn't get any result

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you trying to execute the output of `xdotool` while at the same time redirecting it to a file? Those command substitutions would always be empty... Why are you using command substitutions here at all?  Your issue is probably a timing issue as `gcalculator` would probably not have had time to map a window before `xdotool` is launched, but I'm not sure as I don't know what either command does.

Comment: As you probably noticed I'm not very good at this but, as I said, I didn't find the answer I was looking for in online tutorials and other forums or questions.

Comment: @Kusalananda command subsitution was useless, indeed. gcalculator is a simple gui calculator; `xdotool search --name galculator` finds a window whose title contains word "galculator" and returns a number. I need it redirected to a file to use it later. Point is, `gedit & xdotool search --name galculator > file`, and `galculator & xdotool search --name gedit > file` work perfectly, issue must be either time needed to map a window (but putting a `sleep 10` inbetween didn't solve) or it can't be done in the same shell. I need 2nd command to run right after the first starts, not when it's done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only needed to add a `--sync` option from the [xdotool manual page](http://linuxcommandlibrary.com/man/xdotool.html)

> --sync
>
> Block until there are results. This is useful when you are launching an application want want to wait until the application window is visible.

Which makes the correct command

```
application & xdotool search --sync --name string_contained_in_the_window_title > file
```

like, in my case

```
firefox & xdotool search --sync --name firefox > firefox.txt
```